# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') react v16

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to access data from commerceJS API fetched on a different module and passed down as a prop, the code only breaks when I call a nested product object with this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source').

Here is my code

//Product.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';

import useStyles from './styles';

const Product = ({ product, onAddToCart }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleAddToCart = () => onAddToCart(product.id, 1);

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={product.media.source}
        component="img"
        title={product.name}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {product.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            ${product.price.formatted}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}
          variant="body2"
          color="textSecondary"
          component="p"
        />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart" onClick={handleAddToCart}>
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: It could be that on initial render, there is no data in your product prop. To deal with this, add conditional attribute (I forgot the actual term, it's called something else) by doing this `product?.media?.source` It won't try to render anything if the data doesn't exist

Comment: Try logging your ```product.media.source``` cause it might be undefined. Also using something like this ```product?.media?.source``` should only render things when they're not null or undefined, as @foreverAnIntern has pointed out

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';

import useStyles from './styles';

const Product = ({ product, onAddToCart }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleAddToCart = () => onAddToCart(product.id, 1);

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={product.media.source}
        component="img"
        title={product.name}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {product?.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            ${product?.price?.formatted}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}
          variant="body2"
          color="textSecondary"
          component="p"
        />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart" onClick={handleAddToCart}>
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';

import useStyles from './styles';

const Product = ({ product, onAddToCart }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleAddToCart = () => onAddToCart(product.id, 1);

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={product?.media?.source}
        component="img"
        title={product?.name}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {product?.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            ${product?.price?.formatted}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product?.description }}
          variant="body2"
          color="textSecondary"
          component="p"
        />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart" onClick={handleAddToCart}>
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll display the image if I delete the className property and access to my object key

Code here:

```
<CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={product.image.url}
        component="img"
        title={product?.name}
 />
```